# insert lines of text into an already existing .txt/.xml file?

Tags: excel, vba, file, text

I've been assigned to update a large, existing XML file with some data from an excel file. I want to use a VBA code for a quicker way to update since the number of excel rows and text lines is quite large and can change in the future.

I've already searched and found varying amount of code on how to read and write into a txt/xml file (doesn't matter which). However I haven't been able to find any on how to write in an already existing txt/xml file without deleting all of it's already existing content.
Just for example purposes, I've written bellow a text on which to work on (I'm not using the original text since it's hundreds of lines long).

```
How to improve on life!
Pro tips:

Enjoy!
```

What I would want is to be able to insert multiple lines of text in that space, either by using a text line as a reference (after "Pro tip:" or before "Enjoy!") or by detecting an empty line and use that as a starting point. I do not know the number of text lines and excel rows, however I do have some reference points in that the file has a preexisting structure, thus I can use the text in some lines as points of reference.

Is it possible to do this in excel VBA?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You cannot directly edit the file. You can iterate the lines of the file writing them to a new, perhaps temporary, file. Or collect all the lines into a data structure first, if possible.

Comment: @Pishti - Referring to the existing XML file, it would be helpful to edit some hints to its **node structure** to define an `XPath` where to locate your search text and to insert new contents using e.g. XMLDOM and its `InsertBefore` method. Or post another question with more precise indications describing the XML file and which code you tried by your own; recommended reading at SO  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Seems like you'd really want to consider different approaches based on whether it's actually xml vs just text.

Answer (score 2):

A text file is sequential. That means that after a line follows immediately the next line. There is no room to insert.

To insert a line in an existing text file, you need to "spool" the file and at the place where you want to "insert" the line, write it and then spool the remainder. The following is an example:

```
Sub spool(myFile As String, myPath As String)
    Dim textline

    Open myPath & myFile For Input As #1
    Open myPath & "tmp.txt" For Output As #2
    While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        ' do your check here and insert the line
        If (myCondition = True) Then
            Print #2, "Hello World!"
        End If
        Print #2, textline
    Wend
    Close #1
    Close #2
    Kill myPath & myFile
    Name myPath & "tmp.txt" As myPath & myFile
End Sub
```